# Ruby 2.4.1 Dir.children( dirname ) returns "undefined method `children' for Dir:Class"

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and trying to learn it. I'm using the latest Ruby version (2.4.1) and the interactive Ruby Shell.

I've come across the `children` method in the `Dir` class. I've tried the example [from the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Dir.html#method-c-children):

```
Dir.children("testdir")   #=> ["config.h", "main.rb"]
```

but it doesn't seem to work, because I get the following message:

```
undefined method `children' for Dir:Class
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you **sure** you are running Ruby 2.4.1? Since the method was only introduced in Ruby 2.4, earlier Ruby versions will raise a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: In irb I've got:

RUBY_VERSION  => "2.4.1"

Comment: I can duplicate this....

Comment: How else can I verify the version?

Comment: Also:

`ruby -v` produces 

`ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be some kind of documentation mess.

The `Dir.children` method was introduced with [Feature #11302](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11302) into Ruby and was [committed to trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/944c455b38f85c5fa1b91390d43d89b692e4c812) and eventually released with Ruby 2.5.0. However, it appears that the patch adding this method was not actually backported to Ruby 2.4 since [`dir.c` of Ruby 2.4.1](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_1/dir.c) doesn't mention the method. It's not immediately clear why the documentation for this method turned up at http://ruby-doc.org/

In any case, it appears you are yet out of luck with this method. You can however use the following equivalent code with your Ruby version:

```
Dir.entries('testdir') - [".", ".."]
```

It will return the exact same values as `Dir.children('testdir')` would in Ruby 2.5 and newer.

Comment: `Dir.entries()` and `Dir.children()` are different: assuming you have testdir/test1 and testdir/.test2, `Dir.entries("testdir")` returns `[".", "..", ".test2", "test1"]` and `Dir.children("testdir")` returns `[".test2", "test1"]`.

Comment: @michau And that  is exactly why I removed those two dot entries (the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`) in my code example.

Comment: Aaah, I thought `[".", ".."]` was the result of the `entries` call, I didn't notice the subtraction. You're right, after subtracting `.` and `..`, the result will be exactly the same.