# Why is 'transform_keys' method undefined?

Tags: ruby

This example is taken directly from the [Ruby 2.4.1 documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys), and I can confirm I am running 2.4.1:

```
({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}).transform_keys {|k| k.to_s}
```

When I execute it, I receive the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `transform_keys' for {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}:Hash
```

Why is the `transform_keys` method not defined?

Comment: That method, despite what the documentation says, did not ship in Ruby 2.4.1. It is odd that one shipped without the other. Strangely 2.4.2 does not have this method either, so it's either a bug in the documentation, or a missing feature in the 2.4.x branch.

Answer (score 6):

As observed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45719685/421705), it appears that http://ruby-doc.org currently (erroneously) generates the documentation for Ruby 2.4.1 based on Ruby trunk instead of the actually released 2.4.1 version.

Unfortunately, the `Hash#transform_keys` method is not yet released as part of any 2.4 release. It was developed and comitted to Ruby trunk with [Feature #13583](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13583) but was not (yet) backported to the stable 2.4 branch.

As a workaround for that, you can use this method instead:

```
def transform_keys(hash)
  result = {}
  hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    result[yield(key)] = value
  end
  result
end
```

Equivalently (that is: a bit shorter but also a slightly slower) you could use this:

```
def transform_keys(hash)
  hash.keys.each_with_object({}) do |key, result|
    result[yield(key)] = hash[key]
  end
end
```

If you are bold, you can add this as a core-patch to the `Hash` class where you then just have to replace every mention of `hash` with `self`.

Note that ActiveSupport (i.e. Rails) brings a core-patch with this exact method since about forever. They use a mixture of both implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Holger, you inspired me.

This works for converting keys from string to symbol also for **nested hashes**, as I needed:

```
class Hash

  def keys_to_sym
    result = {}
    self.each_pair do |key, value|
       value = value.keys_to_sym if value.class == Hash
       result[key.to_sym] = value
    end
  result
  end

end
```

So you can transform this:

```
h = {
  "key1"=>"value1",
  "key2"=>"value2",
  "key3"=>{"key4"=>"value4", "key5"=>"value5"},
  "key6"=>{"key7"=>"value7", "key8"=>{"key9"=>"value9"}}
}
```

into this:

```
h_transformed = {
  :key1=>"value1",
  :key2=>"value2",
  :key3=>{:key4=>"value4", :key5=>"value5"},
  :key6=>{:key7=>"value7", :key8=>{:key9=>"value9"}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems like you are trying this code in ruby shell.(irb)

But it's available in Rails.

```
> (irb): ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}).transform_keys {|k| k.to_s} 
  NoMethodError: undefined method `transform_keys' for {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}:Hash    
  from (irb):1
  from /home/chitresh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Use rails console via command  `rails console` or `rails c`

```
> ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}).transform_keys {|k| k.to_s}
 => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```